# Are Crucible Forges one use only?

Tags: path-of-exile

I'm new to the game and don't want to waste Crucible Forges. Can you use [Crucible Forge](https://www.poe-vault.com/guides/crucible-league-mechanic-guide#crucible-forge) for as many different weapons as you want? Or once you use it to improve a weapon you will limit improvement of your future weapons?